# Is the question below ontopic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, acceptable-questions

I am pretty sure this has been coming and going on the web for a while, but I could not find a list of all the girls/elements.

[image: Periodic table of Anime Girls...]

Some are easy to know. Some not so much.

The most obvious ones...

- H - Suzumiya Haruhi (The melancholy of Suzumiya Haruhi)
- B - Belldandy (Ah! My Goddess)
- N - Nagato Yuuuki (The melancholy of Suzumiya Haruhi)
- C - C2 (Code Geass)
- As - Asuka Langley Soryu (Evangelion)
- Ra - Ayanami Rei (Evangelion)
- Cs - Kinomoto Sakura (Cardcaptor Sakura)

So at this point the people that made this linked the element to the series name instead of the character at some point...

Like

- Db Bulma (Dragon Ball)

Or just part of it:

- Rg - Misaka Mikoto (A certain scientific **Railgun**)

Or it makes no apparent sense:

- Tl - Shirai Kuroko (A certain scientific Railgun)  <sup>Probably because of her power, Teleport??</sup>

So for some fun, post in the answers below what characters did you find, the series they came from, and what link from their name to the element symbol.

You don't need to nail all of them to answer. But do your best.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an identification question, just posted on meta instead of the main site

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure this is off-topic due to it essentially being multiple identification questions in one post.

To avoid posts attempting to answer, i'll close this meta - but feel free to bring the question to [chat :)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-)

Comment: Nah, that is fine. I posted to meta just to sandbox it. Delete it if you feel like.